# Error-aware bootloader for Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, linux, assembly, raspberry-pi, bare-metal

I want to write a simple bootloader for the Raspberry Pi. The main purpose of this bootloader is to enable a Raspberry Pi at a remote location, to recover from kernel updates that make the device unbootable as the result of a kernel panic. The procedure for updating the kernel should be like this:

The default Linux kernel is `/boot/rpi-kernel.img` and the string 'rpi-kernel.img' is written in `/boot/default-kernel.txt`. The kernel parameter 'panic=10' has been added to 'cmdline=' in `/boot/config.txt`.

1. Connect to the Raspberry Pi over SSH.
2. Copy `/boot/rpi-kernel.img` to `/boot/rpi-kernel-fallback.img`
3. Create empty file `/boot/kernel_update`
4. Download kernel update and move it to `/boot/rpi-kernel.img`
5. Reboot

*This is the design for the bootloader I have thought up in pseudocode:*

```
read kernel parameters passed from start.elf

if empty file '/boot/kernel_update' does not exists

    boot kernel defined in '/boot/default-kernel.txt' with kernel parameters passed from start.elf

else

    if empty file '/boot/boot_kernel_update' exists

        write string 'rpi-kernel-fallback.img' to file '/boot/default-kernel.txt'
        delete file '/boot/kernel_update'
        delete file '/boot/boot_kernel_update'
        create empty file '/boot/kernel_update_failed'
        boot kernel 'rpi-kernel-fallback.img' with kernel parameters passed from start.elf

    else

        create empty file '/boot/boot_kernel_update'
        boot kernel '/boot/rpi-kernel.img' with kernel parameters passed from start.elf
```

As a last step in the boot process, a shell script will check if the `/boot/kernel_update` exists and then if network is functional and the environment is sane, before removing `/boot/kernel_update`.

I want to make the bootloader as clean and simple as possible, with no support for HDMI, USB, Ethernet, serial etc. The problem is that I'm not sure how to get started with this.

**The main challenges are to read from and write to the FAT32 filesystem on the SD card, and booting the Linux kernel. Everything has to happen from bare metal on the Raspberry Pi.**

**Any code examples, resources, suggestions ect. on doing this would be very helpful.**

Comment: You might get more help on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have already asked a question similar to this on that site, but no answers. I think raspberrypi.stackexchange.com is more for general questions to Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I think you should come up with some actual code instead of just pseudo-code. Take a look into uboot sources, that should provide you with a starting point for a possible fork instead of writing all that from scratch.